# How do I show the icon next to the mode dropdown list?

Tags: interface

I'm just watching a video, and in this video I see the following icon:

[image]

In my GUI, it doesn't show.

How do I show it?

Here is what it looks like for me:
[image]

Thank you very much!

Comment: this is the 3D viewport icon, what do you mean when you say that it doesn't show, could you please show a screenshot? You can press Shift F5 to switch to the 3D viewport

Comment: @moonboots Thanks, I have added a screenshot.

Comment: @ChristopherBennett Yes!!! Thank you!